# Access Windows Azure via REST in C#

Tags: c#, rest, azure

I have access to an account at azure.com. I need to manage it via the REST API. I found the GetRole and UpdateRole APIs at MSDN, but they require some values that I'm not sure about for the URI:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<cloudservice-name>/deployments/<deployment-name>/roles/<role-name>
```

I'm pretty sure role-name is the name of the VM in the Azure management console's "all items" list, and there's a subscription ID field on the VM's dashboard. The dashboard also has a deployment ID, but not name. Is that the same? And I have no idea what the cloudservice-name would be. There's a cloudservice entry with the exact same name as the VM. Is that the name?

Additionally, there's no mention of using login information, or a certificate. Is there a requirement for setting up security on the connection?

I've run several searches, and have found good general information (almost all on MSDN), but no specific implementation information, so if anyone has some good links, I'd appreciate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the subscription ID and the cloud service name.

If you look at the dashboard of the cloud service, you'll see a Deployment Name at the right hand side, just under "SITE URL". It's different from the deployment id which is at the very bottom of the page.

For authentication, you'll need to create a management certificate, install it on the client computer, and upload to the Azure portal at the "settings" page from the left hand side (the very bottom button). Then you can authenticate with that certificate. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460782.aspx) provides some more details about authentication.